# Spark Streaming DStream write in parquet error

Tags: spark-streaming, parquet

Hi guys i have a problem with DStream writing in parquet file. I have structure like this

```
DStream.foreachRDD(
    rdd => {
          rdd.write.parquet("somepath/1.parquet")
        }
    )
}
```

It works fine but in some cases i get error and parquet file created without any information

Here is my log info:

```
15/07/22 10:14:09 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionPartition cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionRDD.compute(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
15/07/22 10:14:09 ERROR DefaultWriterContainer: Job job_201507221014_0000 aborted.
15/07/22 10:14:09 ERROR JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1437538446000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.insert(commands.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(commands.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:281)
    at kafkaStreamReader$$anonfun$main$1.apply(kafkaStreamReader.scala:57)
    at kafkaStreamReader$$anonfun$main$1.apply(kafkaStreamReader.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:631)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:631)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:193)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:192)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionPartition cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionRDD.compute(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.insert(commands.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(commands.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:939)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:281)
    at kafkaStreamReader$$anonfun$main$1.apply(kafkaStreamReader.scala:57)
    at kafkaStreamReader$$anonfun$main$1.apply(kafkaStreamReader.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:631)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:631)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:193)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:192)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionPartition cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionPartition
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ParallelCollectionRDD.compute(ParallelCollectionRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1266)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1256)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1411)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

But as i already say at some times all ok parquet created with received information. Also i note that if i will make a lot of computations at this part of code

```
rdd => {
          **here**
       }
```

number of errors will increase.